# doOnCompleted not called after retryWhen

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-android

I have something like this:

```
            service.getStuff()
            .map(...)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .retryWhen(errors -> errors.flatMap(t -> {
                return otherObservable.doOnNext(someSideEffect);
            }))
            .doOnCompleted(() ->  onComplete())
            .subscribe(onNext() , onError());
```

The `onNext()` executes, and on the `onComplete()` is called on the original observable from `service.getStuff()`

The problem: `doOnCompleted()` does not execute.

the original observable (service.getStuff) is:

```
Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<InputStream>() {
                                     @Override
                                     public void call(final Subscriber<? super InputStream> subscriber) {
                                         call.enqueue(new Callback() {
                                             @Override
                                             public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                                                 subscriber.onError(e);
                                             }

                                             @Override
                                             public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                                                 subscriber.onNext(response.body().byteStream());
                                                 Log.d("HTTP", "calling complete");
                                                 subscriber.onCompleted();
                                                 Log.d("HTTP", "called complete");
                                             }
                                         });
                                     }
                                 }
```

Comment: Why not simply have your onComplete() in your subscribe? Using a side-effect in this case seems completely unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand fully what's happening but after finding [this similar discussion](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/3540) i reimplemented it without flatMap and it works:

```
.retryWhen(errors -> errors.zipWith(otherObservable, dummyZipFunction));
```